# Put single qoute in array output

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, concatenation

I have an array which produces output as shown below :

```
for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
{
    $eq = $emp_q[$i];   
}
```

I need the output in following format : `'a','b','c'`

I have tried using this :

```
for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
{
    $eq .= "'$emp_q[$i]'";  
}
```

But above code is not giving the output I am expecting . Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
<?php
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');

echo "'".implode("','", $arr)."'"; // outputs 'a','b','c'
?>
```

Comment: It would not work correctly if array is empty. You should add check:
`echo empty($arr) ? "" : "'" . implode("','", $arr) . "'";

Answer (score 0):

Where is you comma?

You have to add a comma unless i = 0;